# Separate Typescript files in build config

Tags: javascript, typescript, scope

I guess I have a rather complicated problem.

I use a JS environment in which JS script are executed separately, let's say JS is used as a script language like LUA in minecraft or other games an so on. These script may be called when a user clicks a button and they run on the server side of my application.

I compile my TS files to JS but the Typescript transpiler does not know that the TS files it compiles do exist (life) in the same environment. An example:

**types.d.ts**

```
interface Person {
    name: string;
    age: number;
}

interface Car {
    maxv: number;
    brand: string;
}
```

**person.ts**

```
var steven = new Person();
```

**car.ts**

```
var steven = new Car();
```

For my purpose this is valid code. `person.js` might be bound to a button a user clicks and `car.js` might be a job script on my server. These scripts are executed completely seperatly but Typescript doesn't know that. That's why I get an error that I may not set `steven` to a variable of a different type that before.

Is there a way to tell Typescript "Hey, These files are not existing together"?

I already thought about putting every script into a namespace ...

**person.ts**

```
module person {
    export function run() {
        var steven = new Person();
        // further script code
    }
}
```

... but I don't like that approach.

Comment: split them into separate projects and bundle them as node modules. They'll get compiled separately and can use each other. :)

Comment: I also thought about that but I'd have to do that with +100 files. Not really an elegant solution. Same applies to having one ```tsconfig.json``` for each script.

Comment: are they really not linked by anything? they're just files that do different things all of them bunched together? What's the reason they are together in the first place?

Comment: Also, why are you generating an interface file for all of them? Why not rely on the file itself to tell you the type of what it exports?

Comment: Well, these files *may* import other files. But in most cases they don't.